# Unit-test fail when it shouldn't do

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm working on unit-tests for an application and below is a unit-test I just cant figure out why it fails.

The test result should be that "isosceles" is true and "equalateral" and "scalene" is false, which Console.WriteLine shows that they actually are, but by some strange reason the test fails anyhow. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

I'm using the MSTest framework.

```
    public void isIsosceles()
    {
        Triangle triangle = new Triangle(2, 2, 5);

        var isosceles = triangle.isIsosceles();
        var equalateral = triangle.isEquilateral();
        var scalene = triangle.isScalene();

        Console.WriteLine(isosceles);       // True
        Console.WriteLine(equalateral);     // False
        Console.WriteLine(scalene);         // False

        Assert.IsTrue(true, "Test Isosceles", isosceles);
        Assert.IsTrue(false, "Test Equalateral", equalateral);    // Fails, why?
        Assert.IsTrue(false, "Test Scalene", scalene);            // Fails, why?
    }
```

Comment: Your `Assert.IsTrue(false, ...` code looks rather suspicious.

Comment: .Net public member names should be UpperCamelCase.

Comment: @SLaks I thought it was `camelCase` and `PascalCase`...? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72.aspx)

Comment: @Nate: UpperCamelCase is much less ambiguous.

Comment: @SLaks I see, you're using UpperCamelCase as a replacement for PascalCase (http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5235528). I didn't realize that there was debate over using one or the other. Bottom line is that first letter should be capital for public members. Lets agree on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mis-calling `IsTrue`.
The first parameter is the boolean to test:

```
Assert.IsFalse(equalateral, "Test Equalateral");
```

You can also call `AreEqual`:

```
Assert.AreEqual(false, equalateral, "Test Equalateral")
```

Comment: Calling `AreEqual` for a bool value is bad practice IMHO, makes the code slightly less readable.

Comment: Yes, but that is what the OP might have been *meaning* by the code.

Comment: @McKay I'm not in the business of mind reading, just simply stating that using `AreEqual` for a bool is bad practice for those that may stumble upon this answer down stream.

Comment: @AaronMcIver Which is why I stated precisely what I stated. "Yes" because I agree with you, but also, I think that what SLaks put might be helpful to the OP. We are in the business of helping the OP. He might have made such a simple mistake. Mind reading helps sometimes.

Comment: Seeing as how 3 people (Slaks, myself, and Tudor) mentioned `Assert.AreEqual`, It might be a reasonable assumption?

Answer (score 2):

`Assert.IsTrue` checks to see if the first parameter is true.

What you probably want is:

```
    Assert.IsTrue(isosceles, "Test Isosceles");
    Assert.IsFalse(equalateral, "Test Equalateral"); 
    Assert.IsFalse(scalene, "Test Scalene");
```

But what you might be meaning is:

```
    Assert.AreEqual(true, isosceles, "Test Isosceles");
    Assert.AreEqual(false, equalateral, "Test Equalateral");
    Assert.AreEqual(false, scalene, "Test Scalene");
```

Answer (score 1):

From the MSDN of `Assert.IsTrue Method (Boolean, String, Object[])`:

> Verifies that the specified condition is true. The assertion fails  if
>   the condition is false.

Obviously `Assert.IsTrue(false,...)` will fail.

I think you meant:

```
Assert.IsTrue(equalateral == false, "Test Equalateral", equilateral);
```

Answer (score 0):

The assert statements are used is a wrong way. This would be correct:

```
    Assert.IsTrue(isosceles, "Test Isosceles");
    Assert.IsFalse(equalateral, "Test Equalateral");
    Assert.IsFalse(scalene, "Test Scalene");
```

Answer (score 0):

for the false cases you have to do Assert.isFalse(equalateral... and similarly with scalene